# http://localhost:9870 does not work HADOOP

Tags: hadoop

I am beginner to learn hadoop,i use latest version ubuntu,I have an error when browsing localhost:9870 the browser says that the page does not exist

Comment: You must show more effort and deliver more data to receive helpful response. What have you installed and how did you check the installation is done successfully?

Comment: Are you sure you're running the latest Hadoop version? In previous versions, namenode runs on port 50070

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you need to check you Hadoop daemons are running by entering the command: jps. Here my namenode is also configured as datanode.

[image]

Second, check Namenode Java Process is running with 9870 port or not by entering the command.

```
netstat -an | grep 9870
```

Third, check dfs.namenode.http-address property in hdfs-site.xml

Finally, make sure you have disabled firewall

Answer (score 4):

```
$ bin/hdfs namenode -format
```

then `-format` I can restart hdfs

I don't know why it must be

Comment: Why is it answering the questio ?

Comment: later, now  I can work with hdfs and put file on the hdfs  I'm using hadoop 3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Check port 9000, maybe it is occupied by other programs, you can use sudo lsof -i :9000 to see the process occupying port 9000, as shown below, my port 9000 is occupied by clickhouse
[port 9000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSCFf.png)
Then modify the port in the core-site .xml, I modify it to 9001 here, restart, check the 9001 port, try to http://localhost:9870 again, and it succeeds.
[port 9001](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3PSb.png)
[port 9870](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQFI9.png)